# ImportError: Cannot import name 'ChainMap' (pandas\compat\chainmap.py)

Tags: python, pandas

I have installed and tried reinstalling pandas package. I am having the following error:

```
from pandas.compat.chainmap import DeepChainMap
file: venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\compat\chainmap.py    
from typing import ChainMap, MutableMapping, TypeVar, cast    
ImportError: cannot import name 'ChainMap'
```

I have installed python 3.6, tensorflow-gpu==1.13.1, pandas-1.0.3

Answer (score 1):

Update the python version or downgrade the pandas to 0.25. Pandas 1.0.3 requires python >=3.6.1.

Check this [issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/32917)

Comment: I am using 3.6.8 version of python with pandas 1.0.3. What should I do?

Comment: I'm on python 3.7.3 and pandas 1.0.3 is working fine for me..

Answer (score 1):

I have uninstalled the python3.6.1 version and installed python3.7.3 pandas 1.0.3 version along with tensorflow==1.14 version. This solved the issue.